# Handsontable Grid in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, handsontable

I am trying to use "**Handsontable Grid**"  in a ASP.NET MVC (Razor) project. Have anyone used it before? Is it possible? Could you please provide some sample as a starting point?

Thank You.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but there is really no "real" interaction between Handsontable and MVC.

Handsontable grid is databound to an array. It has no built-in properties where you can set an URL for the plugin to get and post data by itself; you are responsible for handling ajax getting and posting data, as well as marshalling and unmarshalling your json or xml to array.

Javascript performance is crucial for UI responsiveness. Large grid on IE8 may not run well for intense editing. That might not be a real issue since, in my opinion, the real killer feature is cutting and pasting to and from Excel, you can simply advise your users to use Excel if they need to do heavy editing.

Comment: Thanks. We are using Kendo UI Grid and generating excel with EPPlus.